# Webix Datatable cssFormat not printing correct color

Tags: javascript, webix

I configured a webix datatable with some columns, each with property:

```
cssFormat: colorByProd
```

where

```
function colorByProd(value, config) {
    var n = 0;
    var timeToCompare = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (value === config[i]) {
            var time = $$("detalleTurnoGrid").getColumnConfig(i).header[0];

            var n = parseInt($scope.fecha.substring(11, 13));
            var timeToCompare = parseInt(time.text.substring(0, 3));
            if (timeToCompare < n) {
                if (value < 31 && value >= 29)
                    return { "color": "#F7D358" };

                if (value < 29)
                    return { "color": "red" };

                if (value >= 31)
                    return { "color": "green" };

            } else {
                return { "color": "black" };
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

so for each column, the value should be black if the current hour is less than next hour, for example:
[Correct Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCX3x.png) -->Current hour == 11

if now is: 11:00, the column 11:00 and next ones will be black, but the 10:00 column will be coloured (green-yellow-red), this almost works perfectly BUT ,do I get a bug?

For example: If the value number exists in other previous hour column, the 11:00 column value changes colour too, only if the value exists in a previous column:

[Wrong Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k78w9.png)

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your code a bit overcomplicated, you need not use loop inside of colorByProd, as code always returns a color for single cell

```
function colorByProd(value, config) {
  var n = 11;
  var timeToCompare = parseInt(this.header[0].text.substring(0, 2));

  if (timeToCompare < n) {
    if (value < 31 && value >= 29)
      return { "color": "#F7D358" };

    if (value < 29)
      return { "color": "red" };

    if (value >= 31)
      return { "color": "green" };

  } else {
    return { "color": "black" };
  }
  return value;
}
```

Check http://webix.com/snippet/26d4c32e